# Sort an array based on another array which may be incomplete

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have a bunch of SKUs which look something like this:

```
{ id: '1234567', size: 'L', available: true, color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234588', size: 'XS', available: true,  color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234568', size: 'M', available: true, color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234569', size: 'XL', available: true,  color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234573', size: 'S', available: true,  color: { id: 1234 }}
```

I also have an source of truth array that looks something like this:

`{ "1234": ["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"] }`

The app is currently mapping the initial array of objects in order. As you can see, each SKU has the color identifier which is the key for the array of truth.

Normally this would be pretty simple to re-organize. Here's the issue:

The source of truth only returns available items. So, supposing that the inventory for "1234" was out of stock on everything except "XXL" the response would be `["XXL"]`. I need all the other entries (items in the SKU) to show up, just be crossed out as sold out. But they all need to be **in order**.

In other words, if I receive the `["S", "M"]` as the correct order, the result sould look like this:

```
{ id: '1234588', size: 'XS', available: true,  color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234573', size: 'S', available: true,  color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234568', size: 'M', available: true, color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234567', size: 'L', available: true, color: { id: 1234 }}
{ id: '1234569', size: 'XL', available: true,  color: { id: 1234 }}
```

It seems doable but the longer I look at it the less possible it seems. Keep in mind also that the size isn't strictly limited to letters but can be alphanumeric (30D) or just numeric (43) or they could be words - "Full-size" so regular ole `.sort()` won't do.

#### How do I use the source of truth array to rearrange the array of SKUs to be in accordance with the order provided by it?

Comment: You can't sort based on information you don't have.

Comment: Can you pass that source of truth array into compare function, and decide there which one is greater based on that?

array.Sort((f, s) => Compare(f, s, sourceOfTruth))

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan yes and based on index of each element figure out the sorting, however, if you look into his example, how would we know that 'S' is greater than 'XS'. As pointed out, we can't sort based on missing information

Comment: @NizarZizoune I believe he means that sourceOrTruth is sorted already, meaning that if S comes later than XS in that array, it means it is greater.... if this is not true, than you are right!

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan You missing the point, he does mean that. However in the example he gave, we have no way of determining that 'S' is greater than 'XS' since the the sourceOfTruth does not say that --> ['S', 'M']. Hence the missing information